# Pinescript strategy alert not triggered

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have a very simple strategy written for in PineScript for TradingView
The strategy does show Buy and Sell signals on chart, however the alert are not being triggered for some reason.

Here is the code and I have also attached an image of the Buy/Sell on chart and the alert setup. If you see something I am missing please let me know @PineCoders-LucF @PineCoders

```
//@version=4

strategy("PreHaltAlgo", overlay=true, pyramiding = 1, calc_on_every_tick = true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 2, currency = currency.USD)

stratbull = input(title="Enter longs ?", group = "General Settings", type = input.bool, defval=true)
stratbear = input(title="Enter shorts ?", type = input.bool, defval=false)

stratyear = input(2016, title = "Strategy Start Year")
stratmonth = input(1, title = "Strategy Start Month")
stratday = input(1, title = "Strategy Start Day")
stratstart = timestamp(stratyear,stratmonth,stratday,0,0)

timebull = stratbull and time > stratstart
timebear = stratbear and time > stratstart

tier1 = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",close[1]) >= 0.75 and security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",close[1]) <= 3.00
tier2 = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",close[1]) > 3.00
perc_change = ((high[0] - open[0]) / open[0]) * 100
limit_up = perc_change > 9.5

min_vol = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",volume[0]) > sma(security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",volume[0]),30)

// longCondition = limit_up  

if timebull and limit_up and min_vol
    strategy.entry("Long", true, alert_message="{\"ticker\": \"{{ticker}}\", \"action\": \"buy\", \"quantity\":\"100\"}")
if strategy.position_size > 0    
    strategy.close("Long", when = open[0], alert_message="{\"ticker\": \"{{ticker}}\", \"action\": \"sell\", \"quantity\":\"100\"}")
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Try with version5 of Pinescript, the alert from the strategy are better handled

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is due to repaint problem. This could happen because you are using security method that evaluate real time data.
this could fix the problem:  `security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",volume[barstate.isrealtime?1:0])`
and also you could protect the entry by check: `barstate.isconfirmed`